# Cabecera de XML para AEAT sistema SII Suministro Inmediato de Información

Tags: vb.net, xml, webservice, aeat-sii

Estoy generando un XML a partir del webservice ubicado en [Facturas Emitidas AEAT](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_06/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl). Uno de los ejemplos que muestran en la documentación es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:siiLR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd" xmlns:sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
                <sii:Cabecera>
                    <sii:IDVersionSii>0.6</sii:IDVersionSii>
                    <sii:Titular>
                        <sii:NombreRazon>EMPRESAXXXX</sii:NombreRazon>
                        <sii:NIF>A84532501</sii:NIF>
                    </sii:Titular>
                    <sii:TipoComunicacion>A0</sii:TipoComunicacion>
                </sii:Cabecera>
                <siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
                    <sii:PeriodoImpositivo>
                        <sii:Ejercicio>2015</sii:Ejercicio>
                        <sii:Periodo>01</sii:Periodo>
                    </sii:PeriodoImpositivo>
                    <siiLR:IDFactura>
                        <sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                            <sii:NIF>A84532501</sii:NIF>
                        </sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                        <sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>01</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
                        <sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>15-01-2015</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
                    </siiLR:IDFactura>
                    <siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
                        <sii:TipoFactura>F1</sii:TipoFactura>
                        <sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
                        <sii:ImporteTotal>26.70</sii:ImporteTotal>
                        <sii:DescripcionOperacion>CompraXXXXXXX</sii:DescripcionOperacion>
                        <sii:Contraparte>
                            <sii:NombreRazon>EMPRESAYYYYYYYY</sii:NombreRazon>
                            <sii:NIF>94234500B</sii:NIF>
                        </sii:Contraparte>
                        <sii:TipoDesglose>
                            <sii:DesgloseFactura>
                                <sii:Sujeta>
                                    <sii:NoExenta>
                                        <sii:TipoNoExenta>S1</sii:TipoNoExenta>
                                        <sii:DesgloseIVA>
                                            <sii:DetalleIVA>
                                                <sii:TipoImpositivo>21</sii:TipoImpositivo>
                                                <sii:BaseImponible>22.07</sii:BaseImponible>
                                                <sii:CuotaRepercutida>4.63</sii:CuotaRepercutida>
                                                <sii:TipoRecargoEquivalencia>0</sii:TipoRecargoEquivalencia>
                                                <sii:CuotaRecargoEquivalencia>0</sii:CuotaRecargoEquivalencia>
                                            </sii:DetalleIVA>
                                        </sii:DesgloseIVA>
                                    </sii:NoExenta>
                                </sii:Sujeta>
                            </sii:DesgloseFactura>
                        </sii:TipoDesglose>
                    </siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
                </siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
            </siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Mi código para generar el XML es:

```
Dim oSfe As New SuministroFactEmitidas.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas
oSfe.Cabecera = New SuministroFactEmitidas.CabeceraSii
oSfe.Cabecera.IDVersionSii = SuministroFactEmitidas.VersionSiiType.Item06
oSfe.Cabecera.Titular = New SuministroFactEmitidas.PersonaFisicaJuridicaESType
oSfe.Cabecera.Titular.NombreRazon = "EMPRESA EMISORA"
oSfe.Cabecera.Titular.NIF = "A00000000"
oSfe.Cabecera.TipoComunicacion = SuministroFactEmitidas.ClaveTipoComunicacionType.A0
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas = New SuministroFactEmitidas.LRfacturasEmitidasType(0) {}
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0) = New SuministroFactEmitidas.LRfacturasEmitidasType
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).PeriodoImpositivo = New SuministroFactEmitidas.RegistroSiiPeriodoImpositivo
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).PeriodoImpositivo.Ejercicio = 2017 
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).PeriodoImpositivo.Periodo = SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoPeriodoType.Item01
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).IDFactura = New SuministroFactEmitidas.IDFacturaExpedidaType
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).IDFactura.IDEmisorFactura = New SuministroFactEmitidas.IDFacturaExpedidaTypeIDEmisorFactura
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).IDFactura.IDEmisorFactura.NIF = "A00000000" 
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).IDFactura.NumSerieFacturaEmisor = "FA1700001"
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).IDFactura.FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor = Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida = New SuministroFactEmitidas.FacturaExpedidaType
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoFactura = SuministroFactEmitidas.ClaveTipoFacturaType.F1
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.FechaOperacion = Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia = SuministroFactEmitidas.IdOperacionesTrascendenciaTributariaType.Item01
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.DescripcionOperacion = "Venta de mercaderia" 
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.Contraparte = New SuministroFactEmitidas.PersonaFisicaJuridicaType
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.Contraparte.NombreRazon = "EMPRESA RECEPTORA" 
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.Contraparte.Item = "B00000000" 
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose = New SuministroFactEmitidas.FacturaExpedidaTypeTipoDesglose
oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item = New SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta = New SuministroFactEmitidas.SujetaType
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta.NoExenta = New SuministroFactEmitidas.SujetaTypeNoExenta
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta.NoExenta.TipoNoExenta = SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoOperacionSujetaNoExentaType.S1 
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta.NoExenta.DesgloseIVA = New SuministroFactEmitidas.DetalleIVAEmitidaType(0) {}
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta.NoExenta.DesgloseIVA(0) = New SuministroFactEmitidas.DetalleIVAEmitidaType
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta.NoExenta.DesgloseIVA(0).TipoImpositivo = "21"
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta.NoExenta.DesgloseIVA(0).BaseImponible = "100"
CType(oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item, SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType).Sujeta.NoExenta.DesgloseIVA(0).CuotaRepercutida = "21"

Dim xmlSerial As New XmlSerializer(oSfe.GetType(), "")
Dim SufijoFecha As String = String.Format("_{0:yyyyMMdd}_{1:HHmmssfff}", Now, Now)
Dim nombreFichero As String = String.Format("FE{0}", SufijoFecha)
Dim strWriter As New StreamWriter(String.Format("D:\Proyectos\IDI\S.I.I\PruebasGeneracionFicheros\{0}.xml", nombreFichero))
xmlSerial.Serialize(strWriter, oSfe)
strWriter.Close()
```

SuministroFactEmitidas.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas es la referencia al Web Service.

El problema viene cuando serializo para obtener el XML. Mi resultado es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Cabecera xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
    <IDVersionSii>0.6</IDVersionSii>
    <Titular>
      <NombreRazon>EMPRESA EMISORA</NombreRazon>
      <NIF>A00000000</NIF>
    </Titular>
    <TipoComunicacion>A0</TipoComunicacion>
  </Cabecera>
  <RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd">
    <PeriodoImpositivo xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
      <Ejercicio>2017</Ejercicio>
      <Periodo>01</Periodo>
    </PeriodoImpositivo>
    <IDFactura>
      <IDEmisorFactura xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
        <NIF>A00000000</NIF>
      </IDEmisorFactura>
      <NumSerieFacturaEmisor xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">FA1700001</NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
      <FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">03-04-2017</FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
    </IDFactura>
    <FacturaExpedida>
      <TipoFactura xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">F1</TipoFactura>
      <FechaOperacion xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">03-04-2017</FechaOperacion>
      <ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">01</ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
      <DescripcionOperacion xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">Venta de mercaderia</DescripcionOperacion>
      <Contraparte xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
        <NombreRazon>EMPRESA RECEPTORA</NombreRazon>
        <NIF>B00000000</NIF>
      </Contraparte>
      <TipoDesglose xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
        <DesgloseFactura>
          <Sujeta>
            <NoExenta>
              <TipoNoExenta>S1</TipoNoExenta>
              <DesgloseIVA>
                <DetalleIVA>
                  <TipoImpositivo>21</TipoImpositivo>
                  <BaseImponible>100</BaseImponible>
                  <CuotaRepercutida>21</CuotaRepercutida>
                </DetalleIVA>
              </DesgloseIVA>
            </NoExenta>
          </Sujeta>
        </DesgloseFactura>
      </TipoDesglose>
    </FacturaExpedida>
  </RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
</SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
```

Los problemas que me encuentro son:

- No sé cómo poner los prejijos Sii y SiiLR que aparezcan en las etiquetas del ejemplo de la AEAT.
- Las etiquetas del XML generado por mi aplicación tienen el atributo xmlns cuando las del ejemplo no la tienen. En principio no es un problema pero me genera dudas.

Comment: Quizás esto te ayude: [XmlSerializerNamespaces](https://johnlnelson.com/tag/xmlserializernamespaces/)

Comment: Con XmlSerializerNamespaces he conseguido solucionarlo al 99%. El único punto donde no consigo que se solucione es en el tag principal <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>. En el xml que serializo yo con mi aplicación, el tag principal no tiene el atributo xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd" que sería el que agrega el namespace SiiLR con lo que el resultado del xml aplicando XmlSerializerNamespaces es <SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas> en vez de <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>.

Comment: @JaimeCapilla creo que deberías comentar si las soluciones no respondieron a tu pregunta, o aceptar una respuesta si resolvieron el problema, y posiblemente también votarlas +1 si fueron útiles

Comment: Finalmente he optado por atacar directamente a los wpl de la AEAT añadiendolos como referencia a mi proyecto. No he podido generar el tag principal con el Namespace requerido asi que he optado por hacer un replace de la etiqueta para incluirlo. No me gusta la solucion pero la urgencia eata vez ha ganado.

Comment: soy novato en el tema. Entiendo que este sistema SII de haciendo funciona vía SOAP, como para enviar y recibir la información. Voy muy perdido con SOAP. Alguien me puede hechar un cable para saber por dónde he de empezar ?? Gracias.
(soy desarrollador de FileMaker)

Comment: Yo voté la respuesta de Manolo Madrigal. En mi caso lo he montado con PHP/SOAP y tal como dice el también, la conversión de array/objeto a XML la hace el mismo SOAP y no tuve que tocar nada de etiquetas XML. Luego si quieres capturar el XML enviado/recibido, el componente SOAP tienen métodos para eso.

Comment: En respuesta a @JoanSubirós comentarte que yo ya estuve en tu lugar y sé lo que puede intimidar la primera vez que te pones con el SII por eso he redactado una Guia para desarrolladores que la puedes encontar aquí: http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/ Vale la pena mirarselo porque te ahorrará bastante tiempo a la hora de arrancar y tener claro cómo integrarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo he "solucionado" con un replace de la etiqueta en el texto directamente. Es un poco chapuza, pero de momento puedo continuar hasta ver cómo se soluciona de forma más ortodoxa.

Con respecto a los prefijo Sii y SiiLR no son necesarios siempre y cuando llames al espacio de nombres correspondiente dentro de la etiqueta de apertura.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda ;)

Comment: Si. He optado por esta solución ya que no podía conseguirlo de otra forma. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

también estoy peleando con este proyecto (sii) , aunque yo  he elegido C# . Os envio un fragmento de código para incluir los "namespaces" ... creo que me ha quedado bastante elegante  ....

```
public XmlDocument crearXMLFacturastEnviadas(List<clsSIIFacturas> xlFact, List<clsSIIDetIVA> lDetIVA, clsXmlCab xDataCab)

           XmlDocument xmldocFe = new XmlDocument();

           // namespace
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldocFe.NameTable);


            nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", Properties.Settings.Default.nms_soapenv);  // las url están en  un archivo conf. 
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("sii", Properties.Settings.Default.nmsFE_Sii_Env);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("siiLR", Properties.Settings.Default.nmsFE_SiiLR_Env);


            XmlNode docNode = xmldocFe.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            xmldocFe.AppendChild(docNode);

            .
            .
            .
            .



            #region Cabecera XML

            // 1 - <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>  root
            XmlElement xRootNode = xmldocFe.CreateElement("siiLR","SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("siiLR"));
            xSoapBody.AppendChild(xRootNode);

            //1.1 - nodo <sii:Cabecera>
            XmlElement xndCab = xmldocFe.CreateElement("sii", "Cabecera", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("sii"));
            xRootNode.AppendChild(xndCab);

            //1.1.1 - nodo Version
            XmlElement xndVersion = xmldocFe.CreateElement("sii", "IDVersionSii", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("sii"));
            xndVersion.InnerText = xDataCab.idVersion;
            xndCab.AppendChild(xndVersion);

            //1.1.2 - titular
            XmlElement xndTitular = xmldocFe.CreateElement("sii", "Titular", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("sii"));
            xndCab.AppendChild(xndTitular);


            //1.1.2.1 NombreRazon
            XmlElement xndNombreRazon = xmldocFe.CreateElement("sii", "NombreRazon", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("sii"));
            xndNombreRazon.InnerText = xDataCab.NombreRazon;
            xndTitular.AppendChild(xndNombreRazon);


            //1.1.2.2 NIF
            XmlElement xndNIF = xmldocFe.CreateElement("sii", "NIF", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("sii"));
            xndNIF.InnerText = xDataCab.NIFRazon;
            xndTitular.AppendChild(xndNIF);


            //1.1.3 - tipocomunicacion
            XmlElement xndTipoComunicacion = xmldocFe.CreateElement("sii", "TipoComunicacion", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("sii"));
            xndTipoComunicacion.InnerText = xDataCab.tipoComunicacion;
            xndCab.AppendChild(xndTipoComunicacion);

            #endregion


            .
            .
            .
```

Al final el xml generado es  ....

```
    <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
  <sii:Cabecera>
    <sii:IDVersionSii>0.x</sii:IDVersionSii>
    <sii:Titular>
      <sii:NombreRazon>xxxxxxxxxxxx</sii:NombreRazon>
      <sii:NIF>xxxxxxxxxx</sii:NIF>
    </sii:Titular>
    <sii:TipoComunicacion>01</sii:TipoComunicacion>
  </sii:Cabecera>
  <siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
    <sii:PeriodoImpositivo>
      <sii:Ejercicio>2017</sii:Ejercicio>
      <sii:Periodo>02</sii:Periodo>
    </sii:PeriodoImpositivo>
    <siiLR:IDFactura>
      <sii:IDEmisorFactura>
        <sii:NIF>xxxxxxxxxx</sii:NIF>
      </sii:IDEmisorFactura>
      <sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>5008646701166</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
      <sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>05-00-2017</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
    </siiLR:IDFactura>
    <siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
      <sii:TipoFactura>F2</sii:TipoFactura>
      <sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
      <sii:ImporteTotal>9.99</sii:ImporteTotal>
      <sii:DescripcionOperacion>Venta General</sii:DescripcionOperacion>
      <sii:Contraparte>
        <sii:NombreRazon />
        <sii:NIF />
      </sii:Contraparte>
      <sii:TipoDesglose>
        <sii:DesgloseFactura>
          <sii:Sujeta>
            <sii:NoExenta>
              <sii:TipoNoExenta>S1</sii:TipoNoExenta>
              <sii:DesgloseIVA>
                <sii:DetalleIVA>
                  <sii:TipoImpositivo>21</sii:TipoImpositivo>
                  <sii:BaseImponible>8.26</sii:BaseImponible>
                  <sii:CuotaRepercutida>1.73</sii:CuotaRepercutida>
                  <sii:TipoRecargoEquivalencia>0</sii:TipoRecargoEquivalencia>
                  <sii:CuotaRecargoEquivalencia>0</sii:CuotaRecargoEquivalencia>
                </sii:DetalleIVA>
              </sii:DesgloseIVA>
            </sii:NoExenta>
          </sii:Sujeta>
        </sii:DesgloseFactura>
      </sii:TipoDesglose>
    </siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
  </siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
```

Espero que os sirva de ayuda .

Answer (score 2):

Yo también estoy peleando con el SII. Aunque hayáis resuelto el problemilla de forma un poco rara, os comento:

No es necesario serializar para mandar el paquete. Simplemente, manda `oSfe` en la función del cliente SOAP:

```vb
Dim Ws As New siiSOAPClient
Ws.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = Certificado
Ws.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = True
Try
    Return (Ws.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(osFe))
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error al mandar las facturas emitidas: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
End Try
```

La conversión a XML ya la hace internamente el servicio y nosotros no tenemos que preocuparnos en montar el XML. Como dice un amigo mío, SOAP en VS es un juego de niños.

Por cierto, mucho cuidado con los certificados, si no no funciona. Si en Internet Explorer puedes entrar a la página de prueba, con VS también lo podrás hacer, pero si en IE no funciona el certificado, en VS no funcionará tampoco.